# Excel VBA userform. Add data into a new row, below headers

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to insert a new row below the headers, to insert the data of the Userform.

My current code adds the new data in row 4, but it isn't adding a new row in row 4. It is overwriting the data that was in row 4.

```
Private Sub KnopOpslaan_Click()

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

        'Regel invoegen op rij 4.
            If Range("a4") <> "" Then
            Rows("4:4").Select
            Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
            End If

        'Formulier doorzetten naar het excel bestand.
            ws.Cells(4, 1).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Datumbox.Value
            ws.Cells(4, 2).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Tijdbox.Value
            ws.Cells(4, 3).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Opnemer.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to make sure the new line is going in?  You are only checking a4<>"" this could still be true? data from col B?

Comment: There is always data in a4. This because there is a date in it, and the date sets automatically. But the answer of harun24hr works for me. So problem solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in `Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown` this line. Replace the line with 
 `Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`

This is full code.

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

    'Regel invoegen op rij 4.
 If Range("a4") <> "" Then
        Rows("4:4").Select
        Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    'Formulier doorzetten naar het excel bestand.
        ws.Cells(4, 1).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Datumbox.Value
        ws.Cells(4, 2).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Tijdbox.Value
        ws.Cells(4, 3).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Opnemer.Value
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Hard-Coded you Row number while writing data to Row 4. So its updating values always into Row4. If you are actually looking at inserting Row below Row4 and writing data into Row5 then try below. Code will insert Row below Row4 and insert data to Row5 always

```
Private Sub KnopOpslaan_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

    'Regel invoegen op rij 4.
        If Range("a4") <> "" Then
        Rows("4:4").Select
        Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
        End If

    'Formulier doorzetten naar het excel bestand.
        ws.Cells(5, 1).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Datumbox.Value
        ws.Cells(5, 2).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Tijdbox.Value
        ws.Cells(5, 3).Value = VoorraadOpnameTA.Opnemer.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to format your data as a table on the worksheet, this makes it a listobject, you can then use the

```
ws.ListObjects("name").ListRows.Add 1
```

this inserts a row just below the headers, regardless of where the table is actually on the sheet.